# Core Data error - Statement is still active - in main thread

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, core-data

App runs fine first time the simulator, but once new data is saved to Core Data the app will not launch again - crashing before the first view loads with an uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'. There are 75 lines of pre-crash actions in the console, but nothing stands out (to my unskilled eyes).

If deleted, the app can be launched repeatedly until new data is saved to Core Data. After saving new data, it does not help to simply stop running the app or quit the simulator, it still crashes during launch.

Stackoverflow and the apple doc.s consistently suggest that it has something to do with threading, but my code is a bit simple for that - everything is on the main thread. I'd love to find things to try in swift or a swift process to identify the cause / solution.

I'm using the default xcode 7 Core Data stack in the AppDelegate class. Sample data is initially loaded into Core Data in one method, and then successfully loaded from core data. After saving a new record, (not re-launching) newly added data is successfully loaded from Core Data. The problem only occurs on re-launch.

In code, when a new record view controller is instantiated, I instantiate two managed objects with separate entities in a prepareForSegue method:

```
if segue.identifier == "newRecord"
    {
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! NewRecordVC)

        let appDelegate    = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate     // instantiate the delegate methods in AppDelegate

        controller.managedContext = appDelegate!.managedObjectContext       // create context from delegate methods

        let recordEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("RecordData", inManagedObjectContext: controller.managedContext)
        let locationEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: controller.managedContext)

        controller.location = Location(entity: locationEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: controller.managedContext)
        controller.record = Record(entity: recordEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: controller.managedContext)

        print("segueing")
    }
```

In the new record view controller, managed object property values are defined, and the managed context is saved while unwinding.

```
    if (segue.identifier == "UnwindSegue")
    {
        updateRecord()   // managed object properties updated

        do
        {
            try managedContext.save()       // commit changes / save context
        }
        catch
        {
            print("There is some error.")       // if error
        }
    }
```

When the app returns to the master view, the new record is fetched from Core Data and displayed on a table.

BUT when I relaunch the app - sadness.

Comment: Does the save finish?  Can you put a print after the save to make sure it completes?

Comment: @DrWhat Since no one else has responded I am guessing they are like me and puzzled by this.  Can you replicate this in a test case at all?  A test case would let you share the code with me and if it is a true issue with the Library you can then submit it to Apple.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not replicate the issue. I'm trying to re-create the entire project piece by piece, perhaps I will find the step where it will break, but that will take time. I'd be ok sharing the broken project if you explain how / where to put it.

Comment: If you cannot recreate the issue then you know the issue is in your code somewhere.  You are on the exact right track that I would be doing.  Adding each piece of functionality back in until you find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learnt that when something is "discouraged" by apple, it's best to stay away from it.

[image]

Changing the override init in the subclass to awakeFromInsert fixed it, as per [doc.s](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1). Thanks Markus S. Zarra.